# How to save image in current user used only model using Django?

Tags: python, django

model.py

```py
class Imageadd(models.Model):
    image_owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='blood/')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image_owner)
```

views.py

```py
def bloodImage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['pic']:
        image = request.FILES['pic']
        img_obj = Imageadd(image=image)
```

index.html

```html
    <form action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='file' name='pic' accept='image/*' class="custom-file-input">
            <input type='submit' class="button">
    </form>
```

Comment: A code dump isn't a good question... we need more details; please [edit] your question. How do you run the code? What happens? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: I want that when a user uploads their images and saves into under the current user login. using only model not form

Comment: You must create a form to get the image from the user

Answer (score 0):

```
class Imageadd(models.Model):
    image_owner = 
     models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='blood/')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image_owner)
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
       self.image_owner = self.request.user
       super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Another way in views.py

```
def bloodImage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['pic']:
        image = request.FILES['pic']
        img_obj = Imageadd(image=image,image_owner=request.user)
        img_obj.save()
```